# I have difficulties saving the form data after form submission django

Tags: html, django, modelform

I have a form where user can create a team. But, somehow the form data never saved on the db after submission. The form page just refresh and return the form with the filled data.
This happen to any form that I created for the project. I feel too confused as I tried every possible way I can think of, but to no avail.
Any help could be appreciated.

The model

```
#model

#model

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(default='team.png', upload_to='teams_pic/')
    bg_img = models.ImageField(default='team_bg.png', upload_to='teams_pic/')
    cups = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="coach", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    country = CountryField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    lga = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=LGA_CHOICES)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="creator", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fb = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    tweet = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    insta = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='players', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = TeamManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sport:team-detail-view', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    __initial_name = None 
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__initial_name = self.name 
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ex = False
        to_slug = self.slug
        if self.name != self.__initial_name or self.slug == "":
            if self.name:
                to_slug = slugify(str(self.name))
                ex = Team.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
                while ex:
                    to_slug = slugify(to_slug + " " + str(get_random_code()))
                    ex = Team.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
            else:
                to_slug = str(self.name)
        self.slug = to_slug
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


#view

@login_required
def team_create_view(request):
    title = 'Create'
    creator = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        team_form = TeamModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if team_form.is_valid():
            team_form.instance.creator = creator
            team_form.instance.team_form = team_form
            team_form.save()

            return redirect(reverse("sport:team-detail-view", kwargs={
                'slug': team_form.instance.slug
            }))
        else: 
            print(team_form.errors)
    else:
        team_form = TeamModelForm()

    context = {
        'title': title,
        'team_form': team_form
    }
    return render(request, 'sports/team-create.html', context)

#form
class TeamModelForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'What is name of your team?',
    }))
    logo = forms.ImageField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'file-upload',}))
    bg_image = forms.ImageField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    coach = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(), label='', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    state = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Select(choices=STATE_CHOICES, attrs={ 'class': 'form-control',}))
    lga = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Select(choices=LGA_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    town = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Which town your team is ?',
    }))
    cups = forms.IntegerField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    birth = forms.DateField(label='', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    players = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(), required=False, label='', widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    fb = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "Facebook Page link"}))
    insta = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "Twitter Profile link"}))
    tweet = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "Instagram link"}))
    email = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "Email Address"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        exclude = (
            'slug', 'updated', 'created', 'creator'
            )

#template
<div class="row">
                           <form id="form-wizard1" class="text-center mt-4" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

                                       {% csrf_token %}
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Name: *</label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Team Name" />
                                             {{team_form.name}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Recent Coach: *</label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="coach" placeholder="Cup won" />
                                             {{team_form.coach}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>State: *</label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="State" />
                                                {{team_form.state}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Local Government: *</label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="lga" placeholder="Cup won" />
                                             {{team_form.lga}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Town: *</label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="town" placeholder="Cup won" />
                                             {{team_form.town}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Cups Won: </label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="cups" placeholder="Cup won" />
                                             {{team_form.cups}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Established: *</label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="birth" placeholder="Cup won" />
                                             {{team_form.birth}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Players: </label>
                                             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="players" />
                                             {{team_form.players}}
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary next action-button float-right" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
                                 <button type="button" name="previous" class="btn btn-dark previous action-button-previous float-right mr-3" value="Previous" >Previous</button>
                              </fieldset>
```

Comment: show your views.py, forms.py and html templates if you are really serious about getting a help.

Comment: is the `print(team_form.errors)` giving you any information?

Comment: No! It is not giving out any information at all. @Ben

Comment: I will paste the templates later, as now I am little away from my computer. @coderboy

Comment: the error seems to be a minute error. once you show the remaining parts of your codes, a solution should hopefully pop up.

Comment: I have included the template, too. Please, have a look. @coderboy